# Generic Android notification handler

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal, android-push-notification

I am implementing push notifications in my Android application. We are using OneSignal to send push notification. We have an API that keeps track of all the devices and API decides which
devices to send push notification.

API requests OneSignal and OneSignal send a notification to the device.

From Android I get the device token using the following code which is saved on the API and it uses it to send push notifications.

```
public String getGCMTokenForPushNotification(){
    String token = "";
    try {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);

        token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
        return token;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
    }
    return token;
}
```

R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId is the SENDER ID on the firebase consle when Android app is registered there.

As of now I have OneSignal set up on the Android application using

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
                .init();
        }
```

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup

If API is deciding and initializing the device on onesignal and sending push notification. I dont think I will require OneSignal setup on android app. Is that right?
If I remove OneSignalfrom the android app. what should I be using to handle notification coming through.

Reason behind is, as of now we are using OneSignal and in the future if we change the provider we dont have to do anything on the app side.

is there any geniric way to handle notifications on android please.

Thank you for your help.
R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you dont need to use onesignal on client. you can remove that. 
Onesignal document says that 
- Implementing reliable interfaces to the GCM/FCM (Google), APNS (Apple)

So basically its uses GCM/FCM, ideally you can directly use GCM/FCM if you dont have complex scenarios.

Answering your question you can use below thing to receive Push notification, because it comes from Google cloud only ultimately

[GCM docs to receive notification message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream) read document carefully you will get it.

This below method will get you you message

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }

    // ...
}
```

and you can implement GCM/FCM also using below documentation, if you wish to go ahead directly [GCM Docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#next-steps)

But you should use FCM now, because GCM is deprecated now. So here you go
[FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Comment: That is what i needed clarification on. Perfect Uday. Will implement FCM which is the better option.

Comment: Yep true @BRDroid and now with FCM you can do much better things. sending to channels(you can create) or device groups. Even with the Dashboard also And you do get other analytics too. Yes you can implement FCM on the client and irrespective of the services you are using(which is based on GCM/FCM) your app will work fine. Hope i have answered your query. Please upvote if you have found it helpful

Comment: Regarding channels how is that handled or how does it work? is that something Android should do or firebase or API or OneSignal. I did not quite understand how Channels work. This is off topic but your understanding on that would be very helpful.